# How to use fixture for cy.visit()

Tags: cypress, fixtures

I have multiple links to test having the same test cases. I wanted to use fixture but it did not work. Can someone please help? I want to reiterate my tests for all links in the json file.

spec.js:

```js
 cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/trial.json').then((details) => {
                details.forEach((totest)=>{
                    cy.visit(totest.url)
                })
            })
```

fixture (.json):

```js
"totest":[
    { 
      "url": "https:www.link1.com"
    },
    { 
      "url": "https:www.link2.com"}
      ,
    { 
      "url": "https:www.link3.com"
    }
     
    ]
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is inside the `totest` property, so you need to add that

```js
cy.fixture('trial.json').then((details) => {
  details.totest.forEach((totest) => {
    cy.visit(totest.url)
  })
})
```

**One test per URL**

```js
import details from './cypress/fixtures/trial.json'
//OR
const details = require('./cypress/fixtures/trial.json')

describe('tests URLs', () => {

  details.totest.forEach(totest => {

    it(`testing ${totest.url}`, () => {
      cy.visit(totest.url)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! However, I noticed that all links will run in one test. When I generate the report for that, it will only give me one result. So if one link fails, the whole test fails. I want to see which links failed and which ones passed. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, you can do that if you read in the fixture with `require()` or `import`.